# How Do I Use an HTML5 Canvas as a WebGL Texture

Tags: canvas, textures, webgl, compute-shader

I want to:

1. Set Uniform values for case i.
2. Render compute shader for case i to an HTML5 `<canvas>` tag.
3. Use the `<canvas>` contents (case i render output) as a texture in the next render pass.
4. Repeat for all cases.
5. Extract answers into JS from color data.

I'm trying to make a compute shader and need to carry a value per pixel (fragment) on each render pass. A simple example would be incrementing the blue value of a pixel on each render call.

I.e.

```
pass 1: b=1
pass 2: b=2
pass 2: b=3
etc.
```

1. **Is this kind of a shader loop even possible?**
2. **Is there a better way to keep a'carry' texture in video memory for multipass processing (where uniform values must change between passes, unlike standard in-shader multipass processing)?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short answer is *you can't*

You can't currently access the canvas as a texture. Some other solutions

1. Copy the canvas to a texture

   ```
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gl.canvas);
   ```

   Will copy the current contents of the canvas into a texture.
2. Render to your own texture by attaching it to a framebuffer.

   In this case you'd render to a texture that is set as an attachment to a framebuffer and then render that texture to the canvas (assuming you want to see the result and not just do math). [There's an example here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html) and [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html).